# Pronunciation of "A+'s" (plural of "A+")

Tags: pronunciation, plural-forms

Should the pronunciation of the plural "[A+'s](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/A%2B%27s)" be read out "[aes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aes#Noun) plus(es)" ?

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate as I think the issue is whether to pluralise the A as well as the plus sign (if there is a word pluralise).

Answer (score 5):

No, it should be pronounced as though the plus was the plural, even though it is the compound  'A+' that has been pluralised.

So:  "ay pluses"

Comment: [**ey**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ay#Etymology_2)